# Javascript/CSS Image height/width/margin Calculations not taking effect all at once

Tags: javascript, css

I am practicing my vanilla javascript, by writing an image gallery application.

The function I am working on is the swap from my imageRoll to my mainImage.
The swap works fine, and the height/width calculation works fine as well... but when I tell it to calculate the margin of the parent element and the new image, it fails unless you click the source image a second time.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/un64w9hh/2/

Here's the function code:

```
function galleryToMainImg() {
    var gNumList = this.parentNode.classList;
    var gNum = gNumList[0].slice(1,2);
    var imgId = "g" + gNum + "MainImage";
    var imgName = document.getElementById(imgId);
    var height = this.offsetHeight;
    var width = this.offsetWidth
    var styles;
    var ratio;

    imgName.src = this.src;

    if (height > width) {
        ratio = (width / height) * 100;
        styles = "height:100%; margin: 0px " + ((imgName.parentNode.offsetWidth - imgName.offsetWidth) / 2) + "px;";

    } else if (width > height){
        ratio = (height / width) * 100;
        styles = "width:100%; margin: " + ((imgName.parentNode.offsetHeight - imgName.offsetHeight) / 2) + "px 0px;";
    } else {
        ratio = 1;
        styles = "width:100%; margin: " + ((imgName.parentNode.offsetHeight - imgName.offsetHeight) / 2) + "px 0px;";           
    }

    imgName.style = styles;
}
```

Interestingly enough, as long as the images clicked from the gallery are the same layout (portrait vs landscape) it works every time after the first one. But if you switch layout, it breaks every time.

First click:

```
<img id="g1MainImage" src="./images/image01.png" alt="Caption" style="height: 100%; margin: 0px;">
```

Second click:

```
<img id="g1MainImage" src="http://ne.fario.us/designs/ImageGallery/images/image01.png" alt="Caption" style="height: 100%; margin: 0px 9px;">
```

I'm just not sure what is going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you prevent a jsfiddle for that?

Comment: I'll work on getting that up, but the site address is http://ne.fario.us/?r=ImageGallery

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/un64w9hh/

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing with your code for quite a while, your function `galleryToMainImg()` is just fine, ratio and .offsetWidth properties OK. I have eliminated every margin property from your .css and error persists.

Leaving calculations on the side, this works decently (no error, but I still have no margin properties applied by .css):

```
function galleryToMainImg() {
    gNumList = this.parentNode.classList;
    gNum = gNumList[0].slice(1,2);
    imgId = "g" + gNum + "MainImage";
    imgName = document.getElementById(imgId);
    height = this.offsetHeight;
    width = this.offsetWidth;
    styles='';
    ratio='';

    imgName.src = this.src;

    if (height > width) {
        ratio = (width / height) * 100;
        styles = 'height:100%; margin-left: 38%; margin-top: 0%'; /*+((imgName.parentNode.offsetWidth - imgName.offsetWidth) / 2)*/

    } else if (width > height){
        ratio = (height / width) * 100;
        styles = "width:100%; margin-left: 7%; margin-top: 0%";/*+ ((imgName.parentNode.offsetHeight - imgName.offsetHeight) / 2) + "px;"*/

    } /*else {
        ratio = 1;
        styles = 'width:100%; margin: "' + ((imgName.parentNode.offsetHeight - imgName.offsetHeight) / 2) + 'px;"';           
    }*/

    imgName.style = styles;
}
```

Hope it is helpful for future examination.

Comment: This looks like it would only really work if the image sizes are the same on all images, but they're not. I just find it strange that my code works properly if you click the image twice.

I wonder if it's because the image hasn't loaded to the new element yet. I tried using a callback function to tell it to wait until the image had loaded, but it did the same thing, so I took it out.

Comment: I know is not the original solution, but using fixed style values work (even if you have to resize images on an editor). I personally tend to re-build the code/ use the most simple solution rather than getting stuck for some good hours.There is some value changing when you click the wider images, but God knows what is that :), better doing something else than invest too much time.

Answer (score 0):

that's normal because you change the image size on the click. I updated your fiddle to see the alerts. See hier jsfiddle.net/un64w9hh/4/

Comment: So.... if I have the image size change as a function called by the original function, it should work...

Comment: Thank you for your help, Marouen!

Comment: Yes! no pbm, hope you fix it ;-)